# SwiftUI FetchRequest Error: 'A fetch request must have an entity'

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I am building a small app using SwiftUI and CoreData with the SwiftUI App life cycle(no scene or app delegate). I'm getting the following error when I Run+Build my app:

```
'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.'
```

I've checked/verified/re-checked the following:

- My `[app name].xcdatamodeld` file name is the same as what I pass into the NSPersistentContainer `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: [app name])`
- The entity's name `Car` is exactly what I pass into the FetchRequest

```swift
@FetchRequest(entity: Car.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var car: FetchedResults<Car>
```

- I am selecting Manual/None for my entities Codegen and the generated class is

```swift
public class Car: NSManagedObject {}
```

with an extension on Car of `Identifiable`.

Here is my whole view struct that should be(to my understanding) passing the environment around to all of its "child" views.

```swift
struct AppView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: Car.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var car: FetchedResults<Car>
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(car, id:\.self) { item in
                RootView(carData: item)
                    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my @main struct

```swift
@main
struct AutoMateApp: App {
    
    @StateObject var coreData = PersistentCloudKitContainer()
    
    let persistence = PersistentCloudKitContainer()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            AppView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, coreData.persistentContainer.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

When I step through with the debugger the crash seems to appear once the WindowGroup is returned. I'm not sure if that's helpful information at all.

I appreciate all your help, thank you.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. But I am using the Xcode codegen for my Core Data class. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I have the same error after I switched from codegen to manual/none mode. The app in the sim works fine but previews are crashing with `A fetch request must have an entity.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code from the SwiftUI app project template when Core Data support is checked:

**MyApp.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

**Persistance.swift**

```
import CoreData

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
        }
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyApp")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                Typical reasons for an error here include:
                * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                * The device is out of space.
                * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Since this question was asked before Xcode 12 beta 6 Apple didn't have this boilerplate template yet. Since beta 6 I have used that with a different approach to my app anyways. I appreciate the help.

EDIT: Marking this as the right answer since it does suggest what I began doing once beta 6 came out.

Answer (score 3):

Okay so removing the `lazy` from the line `lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {...}()` in the `AppDelegate` helped in my case. Because it seemed that Apples boilerplate code handed of the `NSManagedObjectModel` in the line `let contentView = ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistentContainer.viewContext)` and the FetchRequest accessed that object before it was properly instantiated by the closure and therefore would not be able to find the `NSManagedObject subclass`. Removing the `lazy` from the variable executes the closure right away.

Hope this still helps you and solves the problem in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Apple finally showed us their implementation of how CoreData works with a SwiftUI lifecycle app in their eyes. This appeared in Xcode 12 beta 6. I've since used that and a slightly different approach to the way my app flows which solved my problem.

Comment: removing lazy didn't help me

Comment: thanks this help me, strange because I have older projects where this work just fine

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue today and I think the problem comes from when things are declared and ordered. Removing the entity from the fetch request (which presumably allows it to do things by type inference, at a later point in the lifecycle) removed the problem:

```swift
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [...], predicate: ...) 
private var things: FetchedResults<Thing>
```

It seems possible that `Car.entity()` is evaluated before the environment context is created and injected when you are setting up the preview.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Car.entity()` to static NSEntityDescription.

example

```
struct AppView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: AppView_Previews.entity, sortDescriptors: []) var car: FetchedResults<Car>
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(car, id:\.self) { item in
                RootView(carData: item)
                    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AppView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var entity: NSEntityDescription {
        return NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Car", in: yourViewContext)!
    }
}
```

Comment: How is that supposed to work in a final build?